# I need help formatting a long table in Latex

Tags: spacing, formatting, longtable

I am having trouble formatting my long table over two pages. This is my current code:

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}{p{5cm}p{9cm}}
    \caption{Descriptions of learning styles \citep{Hoerner2013}}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Learning Style}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\\hline
    \endhead 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{1. Visual} & \parbox[c]{\hsize}{People who understand work better when it is in the form of a diagram. Knowledge and concept maps are good tools for such learners.} \vspace{1mm} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{2. Aural} &  \parbox[c]{\hsize}{\vspace{1mm} People who dislike reading, but enjoys hearing someone else say something aloud. Hearing the information is key for such students and group discussions can be of great aid.} \vspace{1mm}  \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{3. Verbal} & \parbox[c]{\hsize}{Verbal learners are people who express themselves easier through writing and speaking. Mnemonics, scripting and role playing are some great techniques to helps those learners.} \vspace{1mm} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{4. Physical} &   \parbox[c]{\hsize}{Hands-on activities rather than lectures or demonstrations appeal to these learners. They are a small percentage of the population, but they learn better through practical experience.} \vspace{1mm} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{5. Logical} &    \parbox[c]{\hsize}{People who are good with numbers and using logic to understand. They easily recognize patterns and often tend to group information to further their understanding.}  \vspace{1mm} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{6. Social} & \parbox[c]{\hsize}{When communicating and socialising with others come easy, someone is a social learner. Studying in group formats and learning from others are their speciality and is how they excel.}   \vspace{1mm} \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{7. Solitary} &   \parbox[c]{\hsize}{People who are more comfortable studying in private and introspective.  The concentration of these students are at their peak when they can focus on their own thoughts without the distractions of others around them.} \vspace{1mm} \\\hline
    \label{learningstyles}
\end{longtable}
```

and it displays like in the picture attached. As can be seen, in each row of the table the hline is very close to the top of each paragraph. I have inserted \ after each \hline which works but then the spacing above each paragraph and below is not the same size, and an empty row is added above 3. Verbal on the second page of the table. I tried adding a \vspace{1mm} behind each \hline instead of a \ so that the spacing would be the same size, but then the programme crashes.

Is there something else I can do to make it look better?

Comment: Sorry, it is supposed to say: I have inserted \\ after each \hline. Not just a single \

Comment: you can edit the text, no need to leave a comment correcting yourself

Comment: you can use the `array` package and have `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}`  to have an extra 3pt space above each row

Comment: Wouldn't a `enumerate`or `description` list be better suited here?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `\hline` and `\cline`; instead, load the `booktabs` package and employ its `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespaces` line-drawing commands.

I'd also replace the interior horizontal lines with whitespace, I wouldn't center-set the columns' contents, and I wouldn't over-use bold-facing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % select a suitable document class
\usepackage{natbib, longtable, booktabs}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Learning Style}
% Calculate maximal permissible width of second column:
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\mylen-2\tabcolsep\relax}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\begin{longtable}{@{}lp{\mylen}@{}}
    \caption{Descriptions of learning styles \citep{Hoerner2013}}
    \label{learningstyles} \\
    \toprule
    Learning Style & Description \\    
    \midrule
    \endhead 
    
    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    
    1. Visual & People who understand work better when it is in the form of a diagram. Knowledge and concept maps are good tools for such learners.  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    2. Aural &  People who dislike reading, but enjoys hearing someone else say something aloud. Hearing the information is key for such students and group discussions can be of great aid.   \\ 
    \addlinespace
    3. Verbal & Verbal learners are people who express themselves easier through writing and speaking. Mnemonics, scripting and role playing are some great techniques to helps those learners.  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    4. Physical &   Hands-on activities rather than lectures or demonstrations appeal to these learners. They are a small percentage of the population, but they learn better through practical experience.  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    5. Logical &    People who are good with numbers and using logic to understand. They easily recognize patterns and often tend to group information to further their understanding.  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    6. Social & When communicating and socialising with others come easy, someone is a social learner. Studying in group formats and learning from others are their speciality and is how they excel.    \\ 
    \addlinespace
    7. Solitary &   People who are more comfortable studying in private and introspective.  The concentration of these students are at their peak when they can focus on their own thoughts without the distractions of others around them.  \\ 
    
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice idea to set the column width using your little calculation. +1

Answer (score 3):

Consider removing the `\parbox` which is the culprit for the weird spacing and replacing it with the `m` columns of the `array` package.

I also used the `booktabs` package for nicer horizontal lines.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{m{5cm}m{9cm}}
    \caption{Descriptions of learning styles}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Learning Style}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{1. Visual} 
        & People who understand work better when it is in the form of a diagram. Knowledge and concept maps are good tools for such learners.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{2. Aural} 
        & People who dislike reading, but enjoys hearing someone else say something aloud. Hearing the information is key for such students and group discussions can be of great aid.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{3. Verbal} 
        & Verbal learners are people who express themselves easier through writing and speaking. Mnemonics, scripting and role playing are some great techniques to helps those learners.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{4. Physical} 
        & Hands-on activities rather than lectures or demonstrations appeal to these learners. They are a small percentage of the population, but they learn better through practical experience.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{5. Logical} 
        & People who are good with numbers and using logic to understand. They easily recognize patterns and often tend to group information to further their understanding.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{6. Social} 
        & When communicating and socialising with others come easy, someone is a social learner. Studying in group formats and learning from others are their speciality and is how they excel.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{7. Solitary} 
        & People who are more comfortable studying in private and introspective.  The concentration of these students are at their peak when they can focus on their own thoughts without the distractions of others around them.\\
    \bottomrule
    \label{learningstyles}
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit

In general, I agree with Mico's suggestions, but should you prefer your provided table style (which I replicated), I would still recommend calculating the column width as suggested by Mico using the longest entry.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength\colOne
\newlength\colTwo
\settowidth\colOne{Learning Style}
% Calculate maximal permissible width of second column:
\setlength\colTwo{\dimexpr\textwidth-\colOne-2\tabcolsep\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{m{\colOne}m{\colTwo}}
    \caption{Descriptions of learning styles}\\
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Learning Style}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Description}} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{1. Visual} 
        & People who understand work better when it is in the form of a diagram. Knowledge and concept maps are good tools for such learners.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{2. Aural} 
        & People who dislike reading, but enjoys hearing someone else say something aloud. Hearing the information is key for such students and group discussions can be of great aid.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{3. Verbal} 
        & Verbal learners are people who express themselves easier through writing and speaking. Mnemonics, scripting and role playing are some great techniques to helps those learners.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{4. Physical} 
        & Hands-on activities rather than lectures or demonstrations appeal to these learners. They are a small percentage of the population, but they learn better through practical experience.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{5. Logical} 
        & People who are good with numbers and using logic to understand. They easily recognize patterns and often tend to group information to further their understanding.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{6. Social} 
        & When communicating and socialising with others come easy, someone is a social learner. Studying in group formats and learning from others are their speciality and is how they excel.\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{7. Solitary} 
        & People who are more comfortable studying in private and introspective.  The concentration of these students are at their peak when they can focus on their own thoughts without the distractions of others around them.\\
    \bottomrule
    \label{learningstyles}
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit 2

As Mico suggested in his comment we have to calculate the width of the bold font-version of the text as it differs from the normal font weight-width. Moreover, there are two more `\tabcolsep` in this example compared to Mico's. The one at the very left of the table and the one at the very right. Mico suppressed them by writing `@{}lp{\mylen}@{}`, where `@{}` is used to reset the `\tabcolsep` locally to whatever dimension is between the braces, so in this case, nothing.

Thus the code for calculating the column widths should be replaced by the follwing:

```tex
\newlength\colOne
\newlength\colTwo
\settowidth\colOne{\textbf{Learning Style}}
% Calculate maximal permissible width of second column:
\setlength\colTwo{\dimexpr\textwidth-\colOne-4\tabcolsep\relax}
```

Comment: +1. Two, minor suggestions for the second table: (a) change `\settowidth\colOne{Learning Style}` to `\settowidth\colOne{\textbf{Learning Style}}`, and (b) change `\setlength\colTwo{\dimexpr\textwidth-\colOne-2\tabcolsep\relax}` to `\setlength\colTwo{\dimexpr\textwidth-\colOne-4\tabcolsep\relax}` (since you don't suppress the whitespace padding to the left of the first column and to the right of the second column).

Comment: You're absolutely right. This is what happens when you just copy and paste. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thank you! This actually works perfectly and is exactly how I wanted the table to look! Thanks for everyone's comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

With use of `xltabular` the width of columns can be determined automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} lX @{}}
    \caption{Descriptions of learning styles}
    \label{learningstyles}                              \\
    \toprule
\thead{Learning\\ Style}  & \thead{Description}         \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{Descriptions of learning styles (cont.)} \\
    \toprule
\thead{Learning\\ Style}  & \thead{Description}         \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{%
        \footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}\\    
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
1. Visual
    &   People who understand work better when it is in the form of a diagram. Knowledge and concept maps are good tools for such learners.\\
    \addlinespace
2. Aural
    &   People who dislike reading, but enjoys hearing someone else say something aloud. Hearing the information is key for such students and group discussions can be of great aid.\\
    \addlinespace
3. Verbal
    &   Verbal learners are people who express themselves easier through writing and speaking. Mnemonics, scripting and role playing are some great techniques to helps those learners.\\
    \addlinespace
4. Physical
    &   Hands-on activities rather than lectures or demonstrations appeal to these learners. They are a small percentage of the population, but they learn better through practical experience.\\
    \addlinespace
5. Logical
    &   People who are good with numbers and using logic to understand. They easily recognize patterns and often tend to group information to further their understanding.\\
    \addlinespace
6. Social
    &   When communicating and socialising with others come easy, someone is a social learner. Studying in group formats and learning from others are their speciality and is how they excel.\\
    \addlinespace
7. Solitary
    &   People who are more comfortable studying in private and introspective.  The concentration of these students are at their peak when they can focus on their own thoughts without the distractions of others around them.\\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]